# Como utilizar botões personalizados?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como fazer para colocar botões mais "atraentes" (editar a sua estética) no app e também como adicionar fontes?

Comment: está bem amplo, mas pelo que entendi quer saber como modificar a aparência de um button e mudar a fonte de textViews/checkboxes... correto?

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar a fonte de um TextView por exemplo: você tem de primeiro adicioná-la ao seu projeto no android studio, da seguinte forma...

1º => Crie a pasta assets em app/src/main/assets... Caso tenha dificuldade para localizar, mude a visualização do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º => copie a fonte (.otf ou .ttf) que você deseja para essa pasta assets que você criou.

3º => no código da sua activity declare a fonte da seguinte forma (no exemplo utilizei a fonte **orange_juice**):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "orange_juice.ttf");
```

**(se a sua fonte for .otf, então coloque .otf)**

Para a fonte ser efetivada em uma CheckBox ou TextView é só fazer o seguinte:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "orange_juice.ttf");

CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

checkBox.setTypeface(font);
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

**(lembre-se de antes adicioná-los ao layout)**

Para modificar a aparência de um button (se foi o que entendi), basta fazer o seguinte:

1º => adicione a imagem que você deseja à pasta Drawables.

2º => nas propriedades do button, selecione a aba background:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3º => selecione a imagem desejada (no meu caso **lamp**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto! Se tiver mais alguma coisa, comente.

Comment: Ah sim entendi , tem algum site que encontro essas fontes disponíveis para download? Obrigado desde já amigão

Comment: https://fontzone.net/ se nn me engano tbm foi lah onde baixei a fonte do exemplo da resp

Comment: **LEMBRANDO QUE NEM TODAS SÃO GRÁTIS PARA USO COMERCIAL** se quiser usá-las no seu app você poderá ter que comprá-las

Comment: Tá bom , cara obrigado mesmo viu me ajudou bastante

Comment: Não deu certo , o aplicativo da erro na hora de abrir , meu código está assim

Comment: assim como? coloque um edit na sua pergunta